# How can I use Castle Windsor instead of this?

Tags: dependency-injection, entity-framework-4, castle-windsor

I have a basic working knowledge of Castle Windsor, but I cannot figure out the DI equivalent of the below code ...

```
    private static DbModel BuildModel()
    {
        var builder = new ModelBuilder();
        var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            if (type.Name.EndsWith("Configuration"))
            {
                var entityConfiguration = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                var xx = entityConfiguration as StructuralTypeConfiguration;
                builder.Configurations.Add(xx);
            }
        }

        var model = builder.CreateModel();
        return model;
    }
```

This is intended to automatically load all the Configuration classes in a EF4 code first scenario.

Ideally I want it to pick up all classes in my assembly based on `StructuralTypeConfiguration`.

Am I barking up the wrong tree trying to use DI for this? If so, is there a better way of doing this than getting type names ending with "Configuration"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `ModelBuilder` depend on collection of `StructuralTypeConfiguration` ([you will need a `CollectionResolver` as well](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Resolvers.ashx?NoRedirect=1#codeCollectionResolvercode_4)).

Register all `StructuralTypeConfiguration` implementations.

`DbModel` should be registered `.UsingFactoryMethod(k=>k.Resolve<ModelBuilder>().CreateModel())`